# long title in table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

Some of titles are too long, and when I make the table of contents, one line is not enough for them. How can this problem be solved? Can I split the title by a certain line break command? Or can I use a short version of the title instead? What commands should be used in the both cases?

Comment: You can use the short option.  For instance, `\section[short title]{very long title explaining all nuances}`

Comment: Yes, my question was answered earlier. I am sorry, I could not find it.

Comment: However, I would prefer to have the full title in several lines in the table of contents. Please let me know if you know how to make it.

Comment: For that you can do, `\section{title \newline more title}`